# How to make horizontal glyphs on navbar to show as vertical menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to show the glyphs as in `example A` for desktop monitors and as in `example B` for mobile when the menu is extended. (The code is the same in both examples, except for the css).

Example A: http://jsfiddle.net/bs773m84/4/

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="header-nav-wrapper container-nav-menu navbar navbar-default white-back">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">                       
                <a alt="" rel="home" href="google.com">
                    <img class="logo" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/cornmanthe3rd/plex-android/48/app-drawer-icon.png"/>
                </a>
                <button data-target="#social-menu" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button">
                    <span class="sr-only"><?php _e('Toggle navigation menu','justmakeit');?></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-11 content">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-6   blue-light-back"><span>Brand</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4 col-md-push-4 red-dark-back">
                        <div id="social-menu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                            <ul class="menu nav navbar-nav navbar-default white-back">
                                <li class="facebook">
                                    <a  href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span><span class="social-name">facebook</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="twitter">
                                    <a href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span><span class="social-name">twitter</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="google-plus">
                                    <a  href="http://plus.google.com" target="_blank">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span><span class="social-name">google+</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="pinterest">
                                    <a href="http://pinterest.com" target="_blank">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span><span class="social-name">pinterest</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Example A css:

```
#social-menu li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
}
#social-menu li a{
    padding: 0px;
}

#social-menu .social-name{
    display: block;
    height: 1.4375em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: 100%;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 1.4375em;
}
```

Example B: http://jsfiddle.net/77m94xf4/4/

Html is the same as in `Example A`.
Example B css: No.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you can use `@media Query` and set your css attribute for each size.
for Example :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px)
    {
        add your css for mobile
    }

@media screen and (min-width: 800px)
{
add your css for desctop
}
```

by @media Query you can set css for each devices. eg:mobile,tablet,desktop.

[Learn more about @media query](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: Just before I answered to myself as I found the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

I added @media Query to revert CSS of the menu items for mobile.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 767px){
    #social-menu li{
        display:block
    }
    #social-menu .social-name{
        display: inline;
        height: none;
        overflow: none;
        text-indent: none;
        white-space: none;
        width: none;
    }    
}
```